# Multiple Vagrant provisions

Tags: vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile that creates two machines. I need to run scripts on these machines in the order 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2

I can run the first set of scripts easily enough, but I can't figure out how to run the second script on the first machine after the second machine has been built.

I have tried using Vagrant Triggers, and while I can then run a second script on the first machine, it's before the second machine has built.

Is there any way I can apply the scripts in this order?

Answer (score 1):

I found that a way to do this was to have a second Vagrantfile with different provisioning scripts but pointing to the same machines. When the second Vagrantfile runs after the first it provisions them with the new code.